# How do I have two different apps on heroku with two different branches on the same repository, while choosing my own app names?

Tags: heroku

This isn't critical, but annoying.

I have an app that regularly runs as a web server, but uses another app I created to run a rest server with a specific config file if an environment variable is set. (it's simpler than it sounds)

I've used:

```
heroku create --remote web_server
> created terriblename123.heroku.com
heroku create --remote rest_server
> created existentialcrisis345.heroku.com
```

and that works, but the apps have weird names. When i go to rename the apps through the web console I get a warning that the remote may break.

Honestly, using this method appears to be very brittle. I don't know how to switch between apps in heroku. There doesn't appear to be state or a way to say which app I'm configuring with the heroku commands.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, can you just use the `-a` flag on your heroku commands to specify which app you're configuring? E.g. `heroku your-command -a your-heroku-app-name`

Answer (score 1):

Just create multiple remotes in same git repository.

For example I have one repository for `staging` and `production` heroku app.

```
~/code/my_app $ git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@my_git_server/my_app.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@my_git_server/my_app.git (push)
production  git@heroku.com:my-app-production.git (fetch)
staging git@heroku.com:my-app-staging.git (fetch)
production  git@heroku.com:my-app-production.git (push)
staging git@heroku.com:my-app-staging.git (push)
```

You can name the remotes as you want.

When deploying to heroku, you can specify which heroku app or remote should be used.

`heroku push production master` or `heroku push staging master`